# Characterizing the newforms s.t. the associated symmetric square $L$-function has a pole

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, l-functions

I have a straightforward question. Let $f$ be a holomorphic cusp form of weight $k$, level $N$, and nebentypus $\chi$ that is new in the sense of Atkin-Lehner theory. Write its Fourier expansion at $\infty$ as
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_f(n)n^{(k-1)/2}e(nz)$$
and form the $L$-function $L(f,s)$ by the Dirichlet series
$$L(f,s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda_f(n)}{n^s}$$
for $\Re(s)>1$. Then $L(f,s)$ can be continued to an entire function on $\mathbf{C}$, and, by the above normalization of Fourier coefficients, obeys a functional equation relating $s$ to $1-s$. Let $\alpha,\beta$ be the Satake parameters associated to $f$; i.e.
$$L(s,f) = \prod_p \left(1-\frac{\alpha(p)}{p^s}\right)^{-1}\left(1-\frac{\beta(p)}{p^s}\right)^{-1}$$
and then define the symmetric square $L$-function $L(\operatorname{sym}^2f,s)$ associated to $L(f,s)$ by
$$L(\operatorname{sym}^2f,s) :=
\prod_p (1-\alpha(p)^2p^{-s})^{-1}(1-\alpha(p)\beta(p)p^{-s})^{-1}
(1-\beta(p)^2p^{-s})^{-1}.$$
My question is, when exactly is $L(\operatorname{sym}^2f,s)$ entire, and if it is not entire, what poles can it have?

Pages 136–137 of Iwaniec-Kowalski's book seem to answer this question. We know that $L(\operatorname{sym}^2f,s)$ factors like
$$L(\operatorname{sym}^2f,s) = L(f\otimes f,s)L(s,\chi)^{-1},$$
where the Rankin-Selberg convolution $L(f\otimes f,s)$ has a simple pole at $s=1$ iff $f$ is self-dual ($f=\overline f$) and is entire otherwise. $L(s,\chi)$ has a simple pole at $s=1$ iff $\chi$ is principal. Therefore, my understanding is that $L(\operatorname{sym}^2f,s)$ is entire unless $f$ is self-dual with non-principal character. This can happen if $f$ is a `CM form' arising from a Hecke grössencharacter; see https://mathoverflow.net/a/164126/37110 for details. In the special case when $f$ has real Fourier coefficients and $\chi$ is not principal, $L(\operatorname{sym}^2f,s)$ has a simple pole at $s=1$.

Is my understanding correct? Is it complete? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that the definition of $L(\operatorname{sym}^2f,s)$ is not quite what you display, because at a ramified prime $p\mid N$ the Euler factor might be different. See the discussion in the middle of p.133 and the bottom of p.137 in Iwaniec-Kowalski's book.

Comment: Note also that even when $N$ is square-free, the Euler factors at $p\mid N$ are different, contrary to what Iwaniec-Kowalski say on p.133, namely it would contradict Theorem 6 in Ogg's 1969 paper "On a convolution of L-series".

Comment: by the way, @GHfromMO, I mention what I believe to be another error in IK regarding the symmetric and adjoint square $L$-functions in my comment to Jeremy on his answer. You are probably already aware of this mistake, but I thought I'd notify you in case you were not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. Here's a little bit more detail. If $f$ is a CM form, $f$ is associated to a Hecke Grössencharacter $\xi$. If $k \geq 2$, then $\xi$ is associated to an imaginary quadratic field and then $\xi$ is a homomorphism $\xi : I(\Lambda) \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is a homomorphism from the group of all fractional ideals coprime to the modulus $\Lambda$, and satisfies $\xi(\alpha \mathcal{O}_{K}) = \alpha^{k-1}$, provided $\alpha \equiv 1 \pmod{\Lambda}$.

Let $\omega_{\xi}(n) = \xi\left(n \mathcal{O}_{K}\right)/n^{k-1}$. This function is a Dirichlet character, and the modular form corresponding to $\xi$, which is
$$
f(z) = \sum_{\mathfrak{a} \subseteq \mathcal{O_{K}}} \xi(\mathfrak{a}) q^{N(\mathfrak{a})}, q = e^{2 \pi i z}
$$
has Nebentypus $\chi = \chi_{K} \omega_{\xi}$, where $\chi_{K}$ is the Kronecker character associated to $K$.

Now, the symmetric power $L$-functions of $L(s,\xi)$ factor as products of degree $1$ and degree $2$ $L$-functions. In particular, $L({\rm Sym}^{2} f, s) = L(s, \xi^{2}) L(s, \omega_{\xi})$. Self-duality of $f$ is (by the question you linked to) equivalent to the statement that $\chi_{K} = \chi$, and hence $\omega_{\xi}$ is the trivial character, which shows that $\zeta(s)$ is a factor of $L({\rm Sym}^{2} f, s)$ and so $L({\rm Sym}^{2} f, s)$ has a pole.

On the other hand, if $f$ is a CM form with trivial character, then $\omega_{\xi} = \chi_{K}$. Then, the first symmetric power $L$-function with a pole is
$$
  L({\rm Sym}^{4} f, s) = L(s, \xi^{4}) L(s, \xi^{2} \otimes \omega_{\xi}) L(s, \omega_{\xi}^{2}).
$$

Comment: thank you so much, jeremy. this detail is just what i needed.

Comment: moreover, it must be that IK make an oversight on p137 when they claim that if $f$ has real coefficients, $L(\operatorname{sym^2}f,s)$ and $L(\operatorname{ad^2}f,s)$ coincide, since if the definitions (5.97) and (5.98) are valid, in the CM form case, the symmetric square would have a pole, whereas the adjoint square would not. Even in the case of principal character, though, it seems the two would differ by a local zeta function, since $L(\chi,s)$ is missing the local factors at primes dividing the level. Sadly, Iwaniec only treats the level 1 case in his `Topics' GSM book.

Comment: This is the issue of what, exactly, the definition of the Rankin-Selberg convolution of two $L$-functions should be. (The answer is that it is safest to compute it using the local Langlands correspondence. This is mentioned in the errata [here](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~kowalski/corrections-ant.pdf). In fact, I don't think that your Euler product for the symmetric square is correct in all cases.)

Comment: @Owen: I agree. The symmetric square lift is the adjoint square lift twisted by the nebentypus of $f$. Assuming the form $f$ has real coefficients (i.e. it is self-dual), there are two possibilities. If $f$ has trivial nebentypus, then the two lifts are the same (and they are cuspidal). If $f$ has quadratic nebentypus, then $f$ is a CM form, and the two lifts are different (as they have different nebentypus) and neither of them is cuspidal.

Comment: @GHfromMO I mean, it is immediate that if one takes (5.97) and (5.98) as definitions and posits $f = \overline f$, we only have that the definitions coincide if $f$ is level one, so either the definitions (5.97) and (5.98) are wrong or the statement that the two lifts coincide in the self-dual case is bogus. Probably the issue at play here is that these lifts are defined in language that IK are taking pains to avoid here, and their desire to keep everything elementary and analytic is causing this definitional trouble. But, as written, these statements are in direct contradiction.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with (5.97) and (5.98) (as long as one interprets $\chi$ as a primitive Dirichlet character), and I concur that the statement that the lifts are the same in the self-dual case isn't right. I think that IK might have temporarily forgot that $f$ can be self-dual if $\chi$ is non-trivial (although they explicitly point this out on page 131).

Comment: Well even if $\chi$ is principal of modulus $M > 1$ equal to the level of $f$, then $f=\overline f$ but $\zeta(s)/L(\chi,s) = \zeta_M(s) \ne 1$ and $L_f(\operatorname{sym}^2,s)$ differs from $L_f(\operatorname{ad}^2,s)$ by the same arithmetic local factor. But I agree that there doesn't seem to be a problem if one insists $\chi$ be primitive; this seems to be an implicit assumption.

Comment: @Owen: Indeed, (5.97) is not right if $L(s,\chi)$ means the traditional Dirichlet $L$-function. Instead, as Jeremy Rouse suggested, one needs to take the underlying automorphic $L$-function (i.e. replace $\chi$ by the primitive character that induces $\chi$). It is best to consult the original source, see Definition 3.1.3 in Gelbart-Jacquet: A relation between automorphic representations of GL(2) and GL(3).