# L and epsilon factors of Gelbart-Jacquet lifts

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms

I would like to understand better the L-function and epsilon factors attached to a Gelbart-Jacquet lift. Does the fact of being a Gelbart-Jacquet lift translates into strong properties concerning these objects? In particular I would like to understand, for $\pi$ an automorphic representation of $GL(3)$ that is a Gelbart-Jacquet lift :

- could $\varepsilon(1/2, \pi)$ be zero, or can all the twists by quadratic characters $\varepsilon(1/2, \pi, \chi)$ be zero?
- can $L(1/2, \pi)$ or $L(1/2, \pi, \chi)$ be zero?
- are these situations possible for other automorphic representations, that are not necessarily Gelbart-Jacquet lifts?

Any clue on how to understand Gelbart-Jacquet lifts (computationally and in practice I mean) is welcome!

Answer (score 6):

The function $s \mapsto \epsilon(s, \pi)$ has the form $s \mapsto A e^{Bs}$ for some constants $A, B$, so it vanishes nowhere on $\mathbb{C}$. That has nothing to do with being a GJ lift, it's a general property of epsilon factors. Similarly, being a GJ lift doesn't really tell you much about the value at $s = \tfrac{1}{2}$: analytically, the standard L-function of a Gelbart--Jacquet lift doesn't look much different from that of any other automorphic representation of $GL(3)$.

What really separates the GJ lifts from other kinds of cuspidal auto reps of $GL(3)$ is that they are self-dual; so the Rankin--Selberg L-function of $\pi$ with itself, $L(\pi \times \pi, s)$, has a pole at $s = 1$ if and only if $\pi$ is a GJ lift (I hope I've remembered that correctly). See also Peter Humphries' excellent answer to this question: [How strong is the requirement of being a Gelbart-Jacquet lift?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330272)

Comment: For what it's worth, I've found Gelbart and Jacquet's paper (https://doi.org/10.24033/asens.1355) quite useful for computing the local epsilon factors and local $L$-functions, given one knows the local data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these clarifications. Even if the epsilon factor is nonzero, can we have L-value zero at 1/2? Is that possible for instance for all characters ?

Comment: Certainly it is expected that for any cuspidal auto $\pi$ on $GL(3)$, and any finite set of places $S$, we have $L(\pi, \chi, 1/2) \ne 0$ for all but finitely many finite-order characters $\chi$ unram outside $S$; but I don't think this is known (whether or not $\pi$ is a GJ lift).

Comment: With that being said, the $L$-function of a self-dual Gelbart-Jacquet lift $\Pi$ whose epsilon factor satisfies $\epsilon(1/2,\Pi) = -1$ trivially vanishes at $s = 1/2$.

Comment: Agreed, but twisting by a Dirichlet char will change the $\epsilon$-factor.