# Does the symmetric square L-function vanish at one?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions

Take a cuspidal automorphic representation $\pi$ of $GL(3)$ over a number field. My question is quite straightforward and can be related to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178654/characterizing-the-newforms-s-t-the-associated-symmetric-square-l-function-ha) :

> Can $L(1, \pi, \mathrm{sym}^2)$ be zero? If yes, is there any extra assumption ensuring it cannot?

I know that we have the splitting $L(s, \pi \times \tilde{\pi}) = L(s, \pi, \mathrm{sym}^2)L(s, \pi, \wedge^2 \pi)$. If we assume $\pi$ self-contragredient for instance, then the Rankin-Selberg convolution has a simple pole at $s=1$. Either $L(s, \pi, \mathrm{sym}^2)$ has a pole at $s=1$ (Gelbart-Jacquet lift case) and in that case it does not vanish ; or it has none and in that case the question rephrases as : can $L(s, \pi, \wedge^2 \pi)$ have a pole of order 2 at $s=1$?

Any new insight or reference on this precise question is welcome.

Comment: No. There are general $L$-function methods (eg Eisenstein series) that show nonvanishing on the edge of the critical strip. http://eudml.org/doc/142439 http://web.math.princeton.edu/sarnak/ShalikaBday2002.pdf

Comment: Also, Bump and Ginzburg show the symmetric square on GL(3) is nice (probably already Shahidi is enough). They consider poles in Thm 7.5. Banks gives a "no Siegel zeros" result. https://doi.org/10.2307/2946548 http://faculty.missouri.edu/~bankswd/papers/1997_no_siegel_zeros_GL3.pdf

Comment: @GHfromMO I should have made a misclick, there is not problem with your very clear answer, thank you very much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For $GL(3)$, the exterior square $L$-function $L(s,\wedge^2\pi)$ is entire as it agrees with $L(s,\tilde\pi\otimes\omega)$, where $\omega$ is the central character of $\pi$. Therefore, $L(1,\mathrm{sym}^2\pi)=0$ would imply that $L(1,\pi\otimes\pi)=0$, contradicting a result of [Shahidi (1980)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183546358). The best known zero-free region for general Rankin-Selberg $L$-functions is due to Brumley (2012): see the Appendix [here](https://www.esi.ac.at/static/esiprpr/esi2403.pdf).